# How to connect a .net console app client to azure data factory

Tags: c#, sql, .net, postgresql, azure

I have created a Azure data factory pipeline as follows:

```
Azure SQL Database --> CSV Blob storage --> Azure Hyperscale Citus.
```

But this pipeline was created on azure datafactory UI.

Now i want to create this pipeline through a console app.

**1.) But i am not able to figure out how to authenticate the client and connect to data factory to execute a pipeline.**

2.) And is this the best way to convert the sql DB --> hyperscale

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create Azure Data Factory pipeline with C# console application, we can use package `Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory`. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net)

For example (I create a pipeline to copy blobs from one container to another container)

1. Create a service principal and assign `Contributor` role to the sp

```
z login
az account set --subscription "<your subscription id>"
# the sp will have Azure Contributor role
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "readMetric"
```

[image]

2. Install SDk

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager -IncludePrerelease
Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
```

3. Create a data factory client to manage data factory

```
string tenantID = "<your tenant ID>";
string applicationId = "<your application ID>";
string authenticationKey = "<your authentication key for the application>";
string subscriptionId = "<your subscription ID where the data factory resides>";
string resourceGroup = "<your resource group where the data factory resides>";
string region = "<the location of your resource group>";
string dataFactoryName = 
    "<specify the name of data factory ";

var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantID);
ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(applicationId, authenticationKey);
AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync(
    "https://management.azure.com/", cc).Result;
ServiceClientCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
var client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred) {
    SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
```

4. Create Linked service

```
string storageAccount = "<your storage account name to copy data>";
string storageKey = "<your storage account key>";
string storageLinkedServiceName = "AzureStorageLinkedService";
LinkedServiceResource storageLinkedService = new LinkedServiceResource(
    new AzureStorageLinkedService
    {
        ConnectionString = new SecureString(
            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + storageAccount +
            ";AccountKey=" + storageKey)
    }
);
await client.LinkedServices.CreateOrUpdateAsync(
    resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, storageLinkedServiceName, storageLinkedService);
```

5. Create dataset

```
string blobDatasetName = "BlobDataset";
 DatasetResource blobDataset = new DatasetResource(
                new AzureBlobDataset
                {
                    LinkedServiceName = new LinkedServiceReference
                    {
                        ReferenceName = storageLinkedServiceName
                    },
                    FolderPath = new Expression { Value = "@{dataset().path}" },
                    Parameters = new Dictionary<string, ParameterSpecification>
                    {
            { "path", new ParameterSpecification { Type = ParameterType.String } }
                    }
                }
            );
            await client.Datasets.CreateOrUpdateAsync(
                resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, blobDatasetName, blobDataset);
```

6. Create pipeline

```
string pipelineName = "mypipeline";
   PipelineResource pipeline = new PipelineResource
            {
                Parameters = new Dictionary<string, ParameterSpecification>
                {
                    { "inputPath", new ParameterSpecification { Type = ParameterType.String } },
                    { "outputPath", new ParameterSpecification { Type = ParameterType.String } }
                },
                Activities = new List<Activity>
                {
                    new CopyActivity
                    {
                        Name = "CopyFromBlobToBlob",
                        Inputs = new List<DatasetReference>
                        {
                            new DatasetReference()
                            {
                                ReferenceName = blobDatasetName,
                                Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                {
                                    { "path", "@pipeline().parameters.inputPath" }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        Outputs = new List<DatasetReference>
                        {
                            new DatasetReference
                            {
                                ReferenceName = blobDatasetName,
                                Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                {
                                    { "path", "@pipeline().parameters.outputPath" }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        Source = new BlobSource { },
                        Sink = new BlobSink { }
                    }
                }
            };
            await client.Pipelines.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, pipelineName, pipeline);
```

7. Run the pipeline

```
// specify the container and input folder from which all files 
string inputBlobPath =
    "<path to existing blob(s) to copy data from, e.g. containername/inputdir>";
//specify the contains and output folder where the files are copied
string outputBlobPath =
    "<the blob path to copy data to, e.g. containername/outputdir>";
 Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "inputPath", inputBlobPath },
                    { "outputPath", outputBlobPath }
                };
            var runResponse = await client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(
                resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, pipelineName, parameters: parameters
            );
```

8. Check result

```
  //Checking pipeline run status...
            Console.WriteLine("Checking pipeline run status...");
            PipelineRun pipelineRun;
            while (true)
            {
                pipelineRun = client.PipelineRuns.Get(
                    resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, runResponse.Body.RunId);
                Console.WriteLine("Status: " + pipelineRun.Status);
                if (pipelineRun.Status == "InProgress" || pipelineRun.Status == "Queued")
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);
                else
                    break;
            }

            // Check the copy activity run details
            Console.WriteLine("Checking copy activity run details...");

            RunFilterParameters filterParams = new RunFilterParameters(
                DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-10), DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10));
            ActivityRunsQueryResponse queryResponse = await client.ActivityRuns.QueryByPipelineRunAsync(
                resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, runResponse.Body.RunId, filterParams);
            if (pipelineRun.Status == "Succeeded")
                Console.WriteLine(queryResponse.Value.First().Output);
            else
                Console.WriteLine(queryResponse.Value.First().Error);
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
```

[image]

Comment: What if the DataFactory is configured to use git? I can't find anything in the demo to show how to write to a given branch. Any idea how to set that in the program?

Comment: Thanks - I was able to create a ApiManagementClient with your solution